# Prepared Statement get wrong result in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have a table with design

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS InsuranceContract (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`enquiryCode` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`contractCode` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`createdAt` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (),
`updatedAt` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP () ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP (),
UNIQUE KEY (`enquiryCode`)) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 COLLATE = UTF8_BIN;
```

Then I was created a procedure like this

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `sp_insurance_contract_get`;
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_insurance_contract_get` (enquiryCode VARCHAR(20), contractCode VARCHAR(20)) 
BEGIN
    SET @t1 = "SELECT * FROM InsuranceContract 
               WHERE InsuranceContract.enquiryCode = enquiryCode 
                     AND InsuranceContract.contractCode = contractCode;";
    PREPARE param_stmt FROM @t1;
  EXECUTE param_stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE param_stmt;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

And I was executed this procedure in MySQL Workbench by this command:

```
CALL sp_insurance_contract_get('EQ000000000014', '3001002');
```

I expected I will receive 1 row result but it selected all records in this table.
If I copy and create exactly this @t1 into plain SQL not using statement, it's correct.

Please help me to fix this error. I'm using MySQL `8.0.19`

Comment: I dont think that your sql is using your parameters.  Looks like it's saying `select * from tbl where field1=field1`

Comment: But you aren't using your parameters in your query? Why do you even need dynamic SQL for this?

Comment: Because I implemented some logic here but it was wrong with select statement that I was posted. Thanks all. Maybe I need refresh my mind.

Comment: Local variables are not available/visible in prepared statement. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90d4b6e69c4c3402771cc5f2c7a1272c - see error message. So both `InsuranceContract.contractCode` and `contractCode` are treated as column name in your prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use placehoders on prepare statements, this is why we use them to prevent sql injection

One other thing never use column names as variables names, databases can not differentiate

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `sp_insurance_contract_get`;
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_insurance_contract_get` (enquiryCode_ VARCHAR(20), contractCode_ VARCHAR(20)) 
BEGIN
    SET @t1 = "SELECT * FROM InsuranceContract 
               WHERE enquiryCode = ? 
                     AND contractCode = ?;";
  PREPARE param_stmt FROM @t1;
  SET @a = enquiryCode_;
 SET @b = contractCode_;
 

  EXECUTE param_stmt USING @a, @b;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE param_stmt;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
WHERE enquiryCode = enquiryCode
```

you compare that named column to itself. The result is true always (unless the column value is NULL).

Change the names of your SP's parameters, so you can say something like

```
WHERE enquiryCode_param = enquiryCode
```

and things should work.

Notice that you have no need of a MySql "prepared statement" here. In the MySql / MariaDb world prepared statements are used for dynamic SQL. That's for constructing statements within the server from text strings. You don't need to do that here.

Comment: no they are also used to prevent sql injection

Comment: True. But any injection vulnerability in your application arises when you CALL your stored procedure with untrusted user-provided input. Once your procedure is invoked its parameters are already clean.

Comment: yes, but we don't know in this case, where the ids come from, so assuming the worst seems to be the better way

Comment: OK, just as long as you understand that the prepared statement inside the stored function is both unnecessary and insufficient to protect your system against injection.